# Visual C++ can't write into exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

after I compiled my project in C++ (VisualStudio) around 3-4 times, I can do it anymore due to LNK1168 that stands for "VisualStudio can't write into the exe". I've looked up in my TaskManager, the exe is NOT running. Normally I have to wait for like 5 minutes but that isn't a real solution. Any ideas?

ProcessExplorer just tells me, that the handle is invalid and though can't be closed. It remains open all the time...

Comment: Well either you are out of disk space, have wrong permissions or something has the file open. Use e.g. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check what program has the file open.

Comment: Depending on vs version there is a "host" exe that is probably running as the parent to your app and has a reference to your process' handle. On a clean boot, use promon to see what processes are created by vs when you run/debug your app. Kill 'em.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind is to use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to figure out what process is keeping the file open. Download and start up the tool en select *Find* from the menu. Enter the (partial) file name and it should show up in the search results. Double click to jump to the process and file handle in the main application window. 
I'm guessing Visual Studio is the culprit.

Fortunately, you can also use Process Explorer to close the handle. Right-click and choose *Close Handle*.

Note that it's not a good idea to go around closing file handles on a regular basis. However, whenever you're in a pickle it can really help solve annoying problems.

If I recall correctly, a similar problem existed way back in VS 6. It had to do with incremental compilation. For a more structural solution, try doing a full rebuild from time to time or disabling incremental compilation all together.

Comment: Well, ProcessExplorer can't close the handle as it is "Invalid" but it remains open... Any workaround there? I thought it was Spybot but now I've got the error again!

Comment: Perhaps it's anti-virus software that's scanning the file?

Comment: Another common culprit is the windows indexing service. I usually disable indexing on my source folders. A quick way to find out if that is the problem is to disable the indexing service.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing exactly the same problem (For C# and C++).  I have just discovered that having the `Application Experience` Service disabled seems to cause `EXPLORER.EXE` To keep .exe files hanging around (locked by the `SYSTEM`) for several minutes after running that executable.

The solution to this problem, for me at least, was to re-enable the Application Experience service.  (I had originally disabled it since it seemed unnecessary - Apparently I was wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

Your exe might still be running. Stop it before recompiling it.